# Where does Freak Fortress 2's The Tank theme (titled metalfox.mp3) come from?

Tags: team-fortress-2, game-music-identification

There is a music track in my `Team Fortress 2/Freak Fortress 2/sxh/TheTank/` folder called `metalfox.mp3`. I asked someone in game, who said he remembers that it's from old game but doesn't have the exact name. I have been asking people everywhere if they have even heard where the song is from but they don't know.

Searching for metalfox brings up links from Starfox 64 which I tried listening to the music but none of it sounds like this.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That is a track from a Crash Bandicoot party game called [*Crash Bash*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crash_Bash).

[Metal Fox](https://crashbandicoot.fandom.com/wiki/Metal_Fox) is the level where the song plays, hence the filename.

Comment: Thank you so much, definitely made my day. Been searching for the exact name for a month or so